# Form does not show without focus

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using a C# Form to show a toast-style notification in Windows (The existing balloon notification was buggy and not customizable enough for my needs).

I call the following code on a subthread while polling a server for changes.

```
Thread notificationThread = new Thread(() =>
{
    NotificationFrame notificationFrame = new NotificationFrame("text1", "text2");
    notificationFrame.Show();

    Application.Run();
});
notificationThread.Name = "Notification thread";
notificationThread.IsBackground = true;
notificationThread.Start();
```

However, this form does not always display. I found that it only worked when Visual Studio had focus. I tried running it without the debugger attached, but this causes the form to never show.

Eg.:

1. I run using debugger and keep focus on VS2015, frame shows.
2. I run using debugger and switch to another window quickly, frame does not show.

Comment: Maybe it is because of **notificationThread.IsBackground = true;** , it runs in background and doesn't show.

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong, but I think IsBackground only means that the thread would exit when all other main ones do. In this case, I'm sure that other threads are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be it's hidden, use `ShowDialouge()` instead like

```
Thread notificationThread = new Thread(() =>
{
    NotificationFrame notificationFrame = new NotificationFrame("text1", "text2");
    notificationFrame.Visible = true;
    notificationFrame.ShowDialog();

    Application.Run();
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Also, my window has `TopMost` set to true, so it should be visible.

Comment: Can you confirm whether it's doesn't display or gets hidden?

Comment: I'm not sure. It's not visible, that's for sure. I can execute code to check if you have some.